# Dependency resolution in play - sbt - ivy with classifiers

Tags: playframework, dependencies, sbt, ivy

In my Build.scala I got a dependency (which is in our local Nexus/Maven Repo) which has a classifier:

```
[...]
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.example" % "something-ejb" % "1.0.0" classifier "client"
)
[...]
```

The local Nexus is configured and everything else works well, the dependencies are all fetched. But while fetching the classifier dependency I got this error

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.example#something-ejb;1.0.0!something-ejb.ejb-client (2015ms)
[warn] ==== Example Nexus Releases: tried
[warn]   http://example.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/Nexus_Central/org/example/something-ejb/1.0.0/something-ejb-1.0.0.ejb-client
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.example#something-ejb;1.0.0!something-ejb.ejb-client
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/C:/something-tool/}something-tool/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.example#something-ejb;1.0.0!something-ejb.ejb-client
```

The artifact is in the Nexus but not with ...ejb-client but with ...client.jar (without the ejb). Where does this "ejb-client" come from? I didn't configure that.

I tried using a resolver with a new resolver pattern:

```
Resolver.url("Example Releases Classifiers", new java.net.URL("http://example.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/Nexus_Central/"))( Patterns("[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"))
```

But does not seem to have an effect, the error remains.

Comment: tags this questions with tag `playframework-2.0` if it applies to 2.0!

Comment: I have a similar problem, my ivysettings.xml is the following and I want to pull artifacts from it:

    <property name="ivy.local.default.root" value="${repository.dir}/local"/>
    <property name="ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern"      value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>
    <property name="ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]" override="false"/>


play! won't resolve correctly though, I couldn't understand how to use Patterns like you did at all. solved?

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't solved... Actually I abandoned the whole approach .